# Злословит недруг(,) — значит, есть успех

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Злословит недруг(,) — значит, есть успех.

> Со мною много чего интересного случилось(,) — например, вреча, когда я шёл, я встретил суперкотёнка на улице.

Comment: Можно продолжить: Друг опечален — значит, есть причины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

(1) *Злословит недруг — **значит,** есть успех.*

**Условно-следственные** отношения в БСП.

(2) *Со мною много чего интересного случилось, — **например,** вчера, когда я шёл, я встретил суперкотёнка на улице.*

**Присоединительная** конструкция со значением **пояснения**.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Задачу можно решить методом блоков по Лопатину, **[§ 132](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136).**

Здесь **две предикативные** основы, но предложение осложнено наличием **вводного** слова.

2. В первом примере такие отношения обозначаются **тире**, а во втором случае нужен более сильный единый знак.
3. При **условно-следственных** отношениях перед паузой делается **повышение** тона, такие отношения обозначаются **тире.**

При постановке **единого знака** делается **понижение голоса**, а **пауза** больше. Это соответствует **присоединительным** отношениям.

Comment: Where's the proof? No links have been provided.

Comment: References? It's easy.